# If $F$ is a free group with basis $X$ and $N = \langle \{ g^2 : g \in F\} \rangle$, why is $F/N$ elementary abelian of rank $|X|$?

Tags: group-theory

This seems to be a standard trick - take the subgroup $N$ generated by all squares of elements in a group $G$.  Then $N$ is normal, since the conjugate of a square is a square, and $G/N$ is abelian (because every element has order 2).

But if $F$ is free with basis $X$, we can also claim that $X/N$ is a basis for the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector space $F/N$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\{x_1\cdots,x_n\}$, $F\longrightarrow F/N$, factors throw the abelianisation of $F$ : $$F^{ab}\simeq\mathbb{Z}x_1\oplus\cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}\mathbb{x}_n.$$

The image of N in $F^{ab}$ is $2\mathbb{Z}x_1\oplus\cdots\oplus2\mathbb{Z}x_n$. The quotient is $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^{\vert X\vert}$ of rank $\vert X\vert$.

Comment: Can you explain the line "$F \rightarrow F/N$ factors through the abelianisation of $F$"?  You're saying that $F/[F,F]$ is the group written there?  Then why does $N$ have an image in the abelianisation?

Comment: 1) Yes $F^{ab}=[F,F]$.

2) Any morphism $\varphi :F \longrightarrow A$ is  uniquely given by a composition $ F\longrightarrow F/[F,F] \longrightarrow A $, where $ \pi :F\longrightarrow F/[F,F]$ is the quotient map. Indeed, $\varphi( commutator)$ is trivial..

3)The image of $N$ is $\pi(N) \subset F/[F,F]=F^{ab}$.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

Suppose $\;x_1,...,x_m\in X\;$ are s.t. that

$$\prod_{i=1}^m\left(x_iN\right)=\prod_{i=1}^m(x_i)\,N=N\iff \prod_{i=1}^m x_i\in N\;$$

We can now try to proceed by induction: clearly, for$\;m=1\;$ we get

$$x\in X\cap N\iff x=\prod_{k=1}^rs_k^{\pm2}\;,\;\;s_i\in X$$

and assuming all words here are reduced in $\;F\;$ , we get that it must be $\;x=1\;$ , which is absurd.

Now we can do

$$\prod_{i=1}^m x_i=\prod_{k=1}^rs_k^{\pm2}\implies\prod_{k=i}^{m-1}x_i\cdot x_m=\prod_{k=1}^rs_k^{\pm2}$$

Assuming again reduced words in $\;F\;$ , it must be that $\;x_m=s_k\;$ and the power is positive in the rigthmost factor in that product, so:

$$\prod_{i=1}^m x_i=\prod_{k=1}^rs_k^{\pm2}\implies \prod_{i=1}^{m-1} x_i=\prod_{k=1}^{r-1}s_k^{\pm2}\cdot s_r$$

Try now to complete the argument